# Shell script to tail new lines from log file and grep "error code"

Tags: bash, shell

Is there any way to tail **new lines** from log file and grep particular "error code". The logs will keep on updating and we have to constantly pull new lines from log file in such cases.

Comment: Show your own attempt and a specific problem you encountered. A high-level description doesn't give anyone enough to go on to know if their answer is completely responsive to your real-world use case; we need enough details to be able to test our answers, or authoritatively determine that all the aspects of the question are already answered elsewhere in the knowledge base.

Comment: That said, in general, `while IFS= read -r line; do echo "Processing $line"; done < <(tail -f file.log)` is the very, very high-level overview.

Comment: Check your "man tail" page and check if the logs are rotated --- you might need -F instead of -f.  Do not pipe into tail -f.  You still need the grep part  (that can be piped).  Do not use tail without -f because it will then re-read the whole file

Comment: while IFS= read -r line; do echo "print $line"; done < <(tail -F /var/log/syslog)|grep "Failed with result"  . This way I am able to print the details of latest grep output but it is not allowing to sendmail once the error detects..